# Backbone.js getting response from server after a save()

Tags: backbone.js

I have a mode that saves data to a codeigniter function the codeigniter function returns valid JSON data back if it has an error how do i get the error details that the server returns when using save(). I have the following code that doesn't work

```
this.newproject.save({
            'Objective':Objective,
            "Planner":Planner,
            "NISupervisor":NISupervisor,
            "SiteIDs":SiteIDs,
            "Status":Status ,
            "StartDate":StartDate,
            "EndDate":EndDate,
            "Details":Details,
            "PrjTitle":PrjTitle
        },{
            success:function(model,response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        },{
            error:function(){
                alert("wrong");
            }
        });
```

Success doesn't work at all

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd option to save is an object with 2 properties, success and error.  I'm assuming that you mean that "error" doesn't work at all, and success works fine, based on your actual question text.

```
this.newproject.save({
        'Objective':Objective,
        "Planner":Planner,
        "NISupervisor":NISupervisor,
        "SiteIDs":SiteIDs,
        "Status":Status ,
        "StartDate":StartDate,
        "EndDate":EndDate,
        "Details":Details,
        "PrjTitle":PrjTitle
    },{
        success:function(model,response){console.log(response);},
        error:function(model,response){console.log(response);}
    });
```

The error callback also passes model and response, so the response argument is what you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you've got three hash arguments.  The save method accepts attrs and options as its two arguments.  As such, your code should look similar to this:

```
var attrs = {
  "Objective":Objective,
  "Planner":Planner,
  "NISupervisor":NISupervisor,
  "SiteIDs":SiteIDs,
  "Status":Status ,
  "StartDate":StartDate,
  "EndDate":EndDate,
  "Details":Details,
  "PrjTitle":PrjTitle
};
this.newproject.save(attrs, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(model, response) {
    alert('wrong');
  }
});
```

So your call would not have been able to attach the error function.  The above example should work for you since it combines the success and error functions in the second hash argument.